# Why did Remastersys mess up my folder structure?

Tags: remastersys, custom-distributions

I made a distro of Ubuntu from Remastersys. Everything works except, the places are messed up. The home folder acts as the desktop folder and I can't see my pictures, my videos etc folders inside home. I copied my entire Home folder to `/etc/skel/` before creating the distro. Any advice please?

Comment: You copied your Home directory into /etc/skel/ ???

Comment: copying entire home folder in `/etc/skel` hmm... where was the instruction for doing that?

Comment: No. I coppied every folder begins with a dot. .gimp  .Docky is there a way to fix it?

Comment: whatever u copied to /etc/skel folder will be copied to under / as hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you Remaster your Distro. Open up the file called

`/home/{USER_NAME}/.config/user-dirs.dirs`

Replac {USER_NAME} with your user name, for example : `/home/amit/.config/user-dirs.dirs`

Check out all folder places are typed like this following file, if needed edit as shown in picture below

[image]

If the desire folder is not typed and left blank type it as given snapshot above. Some times some Desire Directories are left blank and won't work. Check all

`XDG_<Desired Name>_DIR="<Required absolute Path>"`

When this is done then copy all, whatever you want, folders, files, ect. to `/etc/skel` remaster will make that default home folder as installation and will copy the same.

to copy and paste alike above pic VISIT [HERE](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1135484/)

Comment: here is the link to pastebin http://paste.ubuntu.com/1135484/